# SQL Server : replace Null values with values from the same column by matching values in a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with some null values in column "date":

```
platform   date         id
---------------------------
web        2018-10-10   1
mob                     1
mob                     1
web        2018-10-15   2
mob                     2
ntl        2018-10-09   3
web        2018-10-12   3
web        2018-10-11   4
mob                     3
```

I want to update null values in 'date' for 'mob' platform by matching the 'id' column from platform 'web'. The result should look like this:

```
platform   date         id
---------------------------
web        2018-10-10   1
mob        2018-10-10   1
mob        2018-10-10   1
web        2018-10-15   2
mob        2018-10-15   2
ntl        2018-10-09   3
web        2018-10-12   3
web        2018-10-11   4
mob        2018-10-12   3
```

Will really appreciate your help!

Comment: MySQL is not the same as SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(date) over (partition by id) as max_date
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set date = max_date
    where date is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery should work

```
declare @table table (platform char(3), [date] date, id int)
insert into @table
values
('web','2018-10-10',1),
('mob',null,1),
('mob',null,1),
('web','2018-10-15',2),
('mob',null,2),
('ntl','2018-10-09',3),
('web','2018-10-12',3),
('web','2018-10-11',4),
('mob',null,3)

update @table
set date = (select max(date) from @table t2 where t2.id = [@table].id)
where [@table].date is null  

select * from @table
```

Comment: I created a temp table with the author's sample data, this does not give the desired result.

Comment: That's because the guy who edited it messed it up.... want to check that out now @zkemppel?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend naming a column `date` as it's a reserved word, but this will give you the desired result assuming there is only 1 web entry per id.

```
UPDATE a
SET [date] = b.[date]
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN MyTable b ON a.id = b.id and b.platform = 'web'
WHERE a.platform = 'mob' AND a.[date] IS NULL
```

[image]

Comment: @scsimon yes it will, take a look at the screenshot I just added.

Comment: Add another null with id 3

Comment: And what if web wasn’t the last date in the order? They never said that it would be.

Comment: That is irrelevant, the join will work as is regardless of order.

Comment: Sure you’ll just pull a random date. And that is relevant sir 

Comment: Do you mean if there are multiple "web" entries with the same ID? because I clearly stated that this answer was assuming 1 "web" entry per ID.  The scope of the question and sample dataset never indicated multiple "web" entries per ID.

Comment: You assumed an order of the data which isn’t possible to do. And yes, assumptions that the small sample data set was within the scope you described is a common issue.

Comment: This works even if the the mob entries come before web, if that's what you are getting at.  I answered the question as given, I'm not here to divine what may happen outside of that scope.

Comment: Notice Gordon used and aggregate function like me for this reason.   Cheers mate! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
UPDATE T
SET [Date] = D
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, MAX([Date]) AS D
    FROM T
    WHERE [Date] IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ID
) TT INNER JOIN T ON T.ID = TT.ID
WHERE T.[Date] IS NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=71d462731f7d3597aeafca6a5690786d)**

Answer (score 0):

```
update a
SET a.date = b.date
from #test AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM #test WHERE platform = 'web') as b on a.id = b.id
WHERE a.date is null
```

Update the tablename `#test` as needed.